# How to create a Python array-like object that can be used like an array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create a type whose instances can be indexed with [], just like a list.

I can use this object like

> my_obj[***]

Comment: When you say "array-like", are you talking about the NumPy term "array-like", or are you just asking how to write a list, or are you asking how to define your own class that acts like a sequence?

Comment: Sorry about my bad English expression. What I call it 'Array like" actually means a type whose instances can be indexed with [], just like a list. ( copy from the first answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think you're asking how to create a sequence type—a type whose instances can be indexed with `[]`, just like a list.

---

The key to doing this is to implement one or more special methods, as described in [Emulating container types](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types) in the docs.

In particular, the special method that gets called for `my_obj[1]` is [`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

For a dead-simple example, let's create something that acts like a list of all of the lowercase English letters:

```
class Letters:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return string.ascii_lowercase[index]
```

And now:

```
>>> letters = Letters()
>>> letters[2]
'c'
>>> letters[-2]
'y'
>>> letters[3:6]
'def'
```

However, this isn't really a complete sequence. For example:

```
>>> len(letters)
TypeError: object of type 'Letters' has no len()
>>> reversed(letters)
TypeError: object of type 'Letters' has no len()
>>> isinstance(letters, collections.abc.Sequence)
False
```

---

If you want to implement a complete sequence, the [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) module is useful, because all of the abstract base classes it provides are also mixin classes that fill in most of the implementation for you. For example, if we inherit `Sequence`, we can just define `__getitem__` and `__len__`, and it'll give us implementations of `__contains__`, `__iter__`, `__reversed__`, `index`, and `count` for free:

```
class Letters(collections.abc.Sequence):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return string.ascii_lowercase[index]
    def __len__(self):
        return 26
```

And now, everything that works on `list`, `tuple`, and `range` works on `Letters`:

```
>>> letters = Letters()
>>> len(letters)
26
>>> reversed(letters)
<generator object Sequence.__reversed__ at 0x15f949f68>
>>> print(*reversed(letters))
z y x w v u t s r q p o n m l k j i h g f e d c b a
>>> letters.index('s')
10
>>> isinstance(letters, collections.abc.Sequence)
True
```

---

Also, I cheated a bit, creating a sequence that just delegates to a different sequence (`ascii_lowercase`) to do all the work. In fact, you can often do that, but sometimes you can't. And when you can't, you usually have to handle negative indexes and slices yourself, which looks a bit uglier:

```
def __getitem__(self, index):
    if isinstance(index, slice):
        return [self[i] for i in index.indices(len(self))]
    if index < 0:
        index += len(self)
    return string.ascii_lowercase[index]
```

(You often want the slice to return another instance of `type(self)`, not a list, but for `Letters` that doesn't make any sense, so I just returned a list.)

---

If you want a *mutable* sequence, like a list as opposed to a tuple, where you can modify values, and maybe add and delete them, there are a few more methods to implement, but nothing hugely different.

---

For a more complete example, see [Creating a new sequence is easy](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2015/07/creating-new-sequence-type-is-easy.html).

Comment: It is really what I want!!! Thanks a lot!